# CDH components version numbers

Tags: hadoop, cloudera-cdh

I have an installed `CDH cluster` and used `hadoop version`, but it returns only with `Hadoop` version. Is there any way to get maybe all installed components version number on a graphical interface? Which command can get for example `Spark` version number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open CM (hostname:portnumber) -> Hosts tab -> Host Inspector to find what version of
CM and CDH is installed across all hosts in the cluster, as well as installed cdh components list with version details

Answer (score 1):

Spark version can checked in using

```
spark-submit --version
```

Spark was developed separately from Hadoop-hdfs and Hadoop-mapreduce as a standalone tool which can be be used along with Hadoop, as such most of its interfaces are are different from hadoop.